# PythonのListについての質問

Tags: python, python3

```
x = [[0] * 3] * 3
a = 1
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        x[i][j] = a
        a += 1
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

の出力結果が

```
[7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9]
```

となる理由がわかりません。
なぜ

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

ではないのですか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

リストの要素のアドレスが全て同じ(同一のインスタンス)、だからです。

```py
>>> x = [[0] * 3] * 3  # shallow copy
>>> x
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> [*map(id, x)]
[140087188915840, 140087188915840, 140087188915840]
```

別個のインスタンスを作成する場合は、例えば以下の様にします。

```py
>>> x = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
>>> [*map(id, x)]
[140087168176192, 140087168988480, 140087168028224]
```

```py
x = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
a = 1
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        x[i][j] = a
        a += 1

for i in x:
    print(i)

#
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```