# python3で空の多重リストを作成するとき、一次元リストを掛け算することについて

Tags: python, python3

python3の二次元配列リストの作り方で、混乱しています。

```
a = [[0]*3 for i in range(4)]
b = [[0]*3]*4

for i in range(4):
  for j in range(3):
    a[i][j] = f'{i}_{j}'
    b[i][j] = f'{i}_{j}'
```

という二次元配列の作り方の違いで、以下のように結果が違ってしまいます。

aのリスト内包表記の場合は、

```
[['0_0', '0_1', '0_2'], 
 ['1_0', '1_1', '1_2'], 
 ['2_0', '2_1', '2_2'],
 ['3_0', '3_1', '3_2']]
```

bのリストを掛け算した場合は、

```
[['3_0', '3_1', '3_2'], 
 ['3_0', '3_1', '3_2'], 
 ['3_0', '3_1', '3_2'], 
 ['3_0', '3_1', '3_2']]
```

この出力結果の違いはどのように理解すればよいのでしょうか

Comment: `b = [[0]*3]*4` の方は shallow copy になっています。

Comment: 関連する質問が参考になると思います。[PythonのListについての質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/88013)、[Python3 でリスト内のリストの要素を一つだけ書き換えたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/71256)

Answer (score 4):

aは別のリスト、bは同じリストを参照しています（metropolisさん, payanecoさんがコメント欄に書いてくれているとおり）。

以下の図は [Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%5D*3%20for%20i%20in%20range%284%29%5D%0Ab%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%5D*3%5D*4%0A%0Afor%20i%20in%20range%284%29%3A%0A%20%20for%20j%20in%20range%283%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20a%5Bi%5D%5Bj%5D%20%3D%20f%27%7Bi%7D_%7Bj%7D%27%0A%20%20%20%20b%5Bi%5D%5Bj%5D%20%3D%20f%27%7Bi%7D_%7Bj%7D%27&cumulative=false&curInstr=9&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) で可視化して分かりやすくしたものです。

[image: aは別のリスト、bは同じリストを参照している]